# Match all text ocurring in between specific strings in a nongreedy way

Tags: python, regex

I have a very long text that contains some sparsely hidden messages. Every hidden message is placed in beetween keywords (lets call them string1 and string2). I am trying to come up with a regex (in Python) that will give me all the hidden messages at once. Let me give an example to be clear:

Say we have the text:

```
Hello @9>ruur>9@ dafa  @9>ruerur>9@ @>ru@9>ruour>9@ur>@, @9>   @9>  @9> @9>@9>opp>9@@9>@9>iiiii>9@@9>@9>@9>@9> >9@>9@>9@>9@9>9@9>@
```

And the keywords are `string1 = "@9>"` and `string2 = ">9@"`. Then the regex should match the following (boldcase font or bold underscore):

```
Hello @9>ruur>9@ dafa  @9>ruerur>9@ @>ru@9>ruour>9@ur>@, @9>   @9>  @9> @9>@9>opp>9@@9>@9>iiiii>9@@9>@9>@9>@9>_>9@>9@>9@>9@9>9@9>@"
```

Please, note the nongreedy behaviour i.e. the match should not in any case contain either string1 or string2 just whatever happens to be in beetween. How would the regex be modified if I only wish to match messages that are of length n or more?

I show my best attempt so far:

This regex almost gets the job done: `r"@9>((?!@9>).*?)>9@"` but not quite as the mathes are:

```
Hello @9>ruur>9@ dafa  @9>ruerur>9@ @>ru@9>ruour>9@ur>@, @9>___@9>__@9> @9>@9>opp>9@@9>@9>iiiii>9@@9>@9>@9>@9>_>9@>9@>9@>9@9>9@9>@
```

Is not so easy to draw whitespace so please take a look at the following picture for further clarification:

[image: Matching pattern].

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Add both `string1` and `string2` in the negative lookahead, then use two other lookarounds to avoid capturing them: [`(?<=@9>)(?:(?!@9>|>9@).)+(?=>9@)`](https://regex101.com/r/pRvqSI/1)

Comment: Alternatively, just match all then extract group 1: [`@9>((?:(?!@9>|>9@).)+)>9@`](https://regex101.com/r/pRvqSI/2)

Comment: Thank you @InSync this seems to work perfect. I have to spend some time breaking down the regex to fully understand it. If I only want to match messages of length n or larger I just replace "+" with "{n,}", right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can negate the existence of what is found before the lookaround, such as other repeated "@9>". This is likely to gather exactly your matches.

```
(?<=(?!@9> ?@9>)@9>).+?(?=>9@)
```

**Regex Explanation**:

- `(?<=(?!@9> ?@9>)@9>)`: positive lookbehind of...

  - `(?!@9> ?@9>)`: not matching

    - `@9>`: @9>
    - `?`: optional space
    - `@9>`: @9>
  - `@9>`: but matching exactly "@9>"
- `.+?`: lazy matching of your needed infos
- `(?=>9@)`: positive lookahead of ">9@"

Check the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/MaKZcg/1).